# R: a way to select rows that select a specific value in a column, However column name is defined as a string

Tags: python, r, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-statements

Whilst normally working with Python, Ive recently come across a situation where I have to use R as my collaborators all only know R.

Im trying to solve the following issue:

In Python I would normally subset a dataframe through pandas with:

```py
desired_column = 'column_name'
df <- df.loc[df[desired_column] == some_value]
```

Now im trying to do the same in R, with a column name as a string. This is key to my script since the column names represent scenarios defined by any future user, with columns indicating whether or not to include certain rows in certain scenarios (0/1 or True/False) and in the script one can adjust the (list of) strinf to determine which scenarios to run.

Hence `df[df$column_name == some_value,]` doesn't apply because the column name has to be in a string to be able to run several scenarios iteratively and for easy usage by other users.

Dataframe example for clarification, where the 0 and 1 represent exclusion and inclusion in certain scenarios that may or may not be run depending on the users input in the form of a (list of) string(s) respectively.

```
species    scenario_1     scenario_2
species_i0          1              0
species_i1          0              1
species_iN          1              0
```

In short: Does anyone know of a way to select rows based on a col_name=some_value in R, where the col name is a string variable?

Cheers,

see above for full explanation

Comment: Refer to columns though `[[...]]` to use variables, `desired_column <- 'column_name'; df[df[[desired_column]] == some_value,] `